# Add voting mechanism to Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I know that Outlook has a voting response option available, but what I'm looking for is the ability to add up/down arrows in a mail item or next to a username, kind of like the online status orb (preferably, but will settle for mail item).  Imagine something like Reddit's or SO's voting system, except in Outlook.

I'd prefer a way to slap a control in there, but if it comes down to custom drawing and capturing mouse clicks, that would work.  I've never built an Add-In, so I'm looking for some direction in the context of my goal.

Thanks!

Comment: I looked at form regions and the built-in voting reply, but they don't appear to be what I'm looking for.  Like I said, I have no experience in this realm, and I want a way to cut through the research about add-ins etc. and start chipping away at this.